# Pgpool mismatch role and pg_role

Tags: pgpool, patroni

I have two postgreSQL servers with patroni and pgpool.

show pool_nodes;

1 stage: node1 - master(role - primary, pg_role - primary), node2 - replica(role - standby, pg_role - standby)

After switchover

2 stage: node1 - replica(role - primary, pg_role - standby), node2 - master(role - standby, pg_role - primary)

Restart pgpool

3 stage: node1 - replica(role - standby, pg_role - standby), node2 - master(role - primary, pg_role - primary)

Is there any case to restart pgpool not manually but after failover/switchover?